# Kubernetes Dashboard - Internal error (500): Not enough data to create auth info structure

Tags: user-interface, kubernetes, dashboard

I have Kubernetes with ClusterRoles defined for my users and permissions by (RoleBindings) namespaces.
I want these users could be accessed into the Kubernetes Dashboard with custom perms. However, when they try to log in when using kubeconfig option that's got this message:

```
"Internal error (500): Not enough data to create auth info structure."
```

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md -- This guide is only for creating ADMIN users, not users with custom perms or without privileges... (edited)

Comment: I saw you quickly resolved your problem. Have you consider posting it as an answer?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update SOLVED:**

You have to do this:

1. Create ServiceAccount per user

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: NAME-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

2. Adapt the RoleBinding adding this SA

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: PUT YOUR CR HERE
  namespace: PUT YOUR NS HERE
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: PUT YOUR CR HERE
    apiGroup: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io'
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: NAME-user
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: PUT YOUR CR HERE
  apiGroup: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io'
```

3. Get the token:

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/NAME-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o go-template="{{.data.token | base64decode}}"
```

4. Add token into your kubeconfig file. Your kb should be contain something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://XXXX
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: YOUR UER
  name: kubernetes
current-context: "kubernetes"
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: YOUR USER
  user:
    client-certificate-data: CODED
    client-key-data: CODED
    token: CODED  ---> ADD TOKEN HERE
```

5. Login

Comment: What do you mean by CR?

Comment: I mean a ClusterRule